# Python: Average of datetime deltas in a for loop (excel file input)

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, average, openpyxl, python-datetime

First time posting, been trying to figure this one out for a bit and feel like I'm either approaching it wrong or over complicating it.

Goal: Ingest excel sheet with 2 columns of dates, find the difference of time between the dates per row, then find the average of all the differences.

I'm using openpyxl to do this, as it's an xlsx. The date values in the cell come out in the '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' format.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
Excel_File = 'C:\Some\File\Location'
wb = load_workbook(Excel_File)
Data_Tab = wb['SheetA']
Dates_A = Data_Tab['A']
Dates_B = Data_Tab{'B']

for A, B in zip(Dates_A[1:], Dates_B[1:]):
    A_str = str(A.value) #converting to string to convert to datetime since I couldn't find another way to do this
    B_str = str(B.value)
    A_conv = datetime.datetime.strptime(A_str,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    B_conv = datetime.datetime.strptime(B_str,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    A_B_Delta = B_conv - A_conv
```

Where I've gotten stuck is how to add all the A_B_Deltas together and get an average.

I would need to figure out how to get the total to input into average, which I guess I could just increment a variable to get this number. Such as:

```
Total_Count = 0
Total_Count += 1
```

But how do I add the deltas to get an average?
I have tried adding them to a variable with no success at this point. I also tried setting a empty datetime object variable but that doesn't appear to be possible as it'll just error out.

Comment: Use `enumerate()` around your zip to count the rows. The conversion to strings is probably redundant, what  are the values in the cells?

Comment: The values are the exact same as a datetime object, ex string of "2020-06-24 04:11:00".
I thought the same thing, however, datetime will error out saying it's already a datetime objected. Even though this happens datetime operations won't work on it without the conversion, as it'll error out as being a openpyxl cell value object.

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing the `cell` object, which is not `datetime` with its `value` which probably is.

Answer (score 0):

```
A_B_Delta = 0  # Initialize variable
denominator = 0  # Initialize variable
for A, B in zip(Dates_A[1:], Dates_B[1:]):
    A_str = str(A.value) 
    B_str = str(B.value)
    A_conv = datetime.datetime.strptime(A_str,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    B_conv = datetime.datetime.strptime(B_str,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    A_B_Delta += B_conv - A_conv  # Use += to increment variable
    denominator += 1  # Use += to increment variable
average = A_B_Delta / denominator  # Compute average after the for loop
```

Initializing A_B_Delta and incrementing it sum up all the time difference. There are many ways you can get the denominator to compute the average.

Comment: Yeah the denominator part is easy. However, the issue there is you can't += the time deltas into a variable set with a 0 integer as it'll error out since the delta isn't an integer

Comment: Got it!

A_B_Delta must be initialized with a blank timedelta object
A_B_Delta = datetime.timedelta()
Thanks for the push in the right thought direction!

Comment: Yes, I forgot you are dealing with datetime. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: You can also study list comprehension, sum() and len() built-in function.  I think it can greatly simplify you code.